# C# The type _ has no constructor defined

Tags: c#, database, linq, error-handling

```
public static class DB
{
    public static Table<Address> Address() { return **new Table<Address>();** }
}
```

For some reason, this code is giving me an error saying, "The type 'System.Data.Linq.Table' has no constructors defined". I don't know if it has anything to do with the fact that Address is referring to a table in an SQL DB. Why is it doing this?

How do I fix this?

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Reda I am trying to make it so that I do not need to call a new Table<Address> when it always refers to the same DB Table.

Comment: @SLaks I don't understand why there is no constructor and I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: A `Table<T>` is something specific in the context of an L2S data-context instance. What do you expect `new Table<T>` to mean, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

The error message is correct. There is no public constructor available for `Table<T>` class. You can confirm that on MSDN: [`Table<TEntity>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).